# show.legend = FALSE overriden by geom_text

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

So I'm trying to remove my legend from geom_bar via the `show.legend = FALSE` command. But something in the rest of my formatting code overrides it and produces a legend with title `as.factor(Last_Reporting_date)` with boxes each a different shade of blue with a year label. If I remove the first `geom_text` line, `show.legend = FALSE` works and the legend disappears but I want the colors to be accurate.
Thanks for your thoughts!

```
ggplot(last_four_years,
       aes(x = as.factor(Last_Reporting_Date),
           y = percent_female, 
           fill = as.factor(Last_Reporting_Date))) + 
   geom_bar(stat = "identity") +  
   scale_fill_manual(values=c("#239CD3", "#8CD7F6", "#239CD3", "#0C45A2", "#0C55A2")) +
   labs(x = "Year",y = "Percent of Total Units", 
      title = "% WOMEN SERVING IN FORMED POLICE UNITS", align = "center") + 
   geom_text(aes(label = paste(round(percent_female, 1), "%", sep = ""), 
      colour = as.factor(Last_Reporting_Date)), nudge_y = 1, size = 5) + 
   geom_text(aes(label = Last_Reporting_Date), nudge_y = c(-5, -6.1, -8.7, -9.2, -18.2), 
      color = "white", size = 5) + 
   scale_colour_manual(values = c("#239CD3", "#8CD7F6", "#239CD3", "#0C55A2", "#0C55A2")) +
   theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
   theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: Try adding `theme(legend.position = "none")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would remove the legends with `ggplot2::guides(fill=FALSE, color=FALSE)`. Also I would put your `ggplot2::theme` to the last line, otherwise `ggplot2::theme_minimal()` could overwrite some of your adjustments